# No feedback with edit limit when reviewing

Tags: bug, review-queues

I've been editing some posts on SO and I have recently discovered that there is a limit of pending edits (5 in my case, I don't know if it's variable).

Then I started to review some posts and I tried to edit one of them.

The thing is, when I click the <kbd>edit</kbd> button in the post **while reviewing**, nothing shows. It only returns me to the top of the page.

[image]

I think it should show the message, as it does when you're not reviewing
[image]

Comment: The limit is 5 pending edits. Unless the site is still in beta, then you can have 20 pending edits. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/168333). It's the same for everyone.

Comment: ... and cross-site duplicate #~25 (I lost count) of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/295232

Comment: What should i do? It's a duplicate, yes, but this bug is there and i didn't read any comment from Mod or Admin with even a "We will have a look on that"

Comment: Just wait. It will be fixed in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).